# jenkins cant connect Daemon

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running a jenkins docker application (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/blueocean/)

I am trying to do a docker run on jenkins but received this error:Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

I tried doing : sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins but it said that jenkins user does not exist. I tried doing add admin also but it said it does not exists also.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you ever figure out how to allow the jenkins to access the docker?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that docker service is up & running, if not verify it by running below command -
`$ sudo systemctl status docker.service`

**Run below command to make it work -**
`$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
Log out/in to activate the changes to groups

**Explanation -**

Change user `jenkins` with the username which you are logged in on your host -

`$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

> Do a `echo $USER` to view your current user.

Log out/in to activate the changes to groups, then you can do a `docker run .....` successfully.

Note - Jenkins user exists inside the docker container & not on your host machine.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Comment: Hihi i did that also where sudeo usermod -aG docker $user but it didnt work still. 

echo $USER give me vagrant. 

the jenkins user exists inside the docker container so how do I make him a part of it?

Comment: Logout & log back in. It is supposed to work. `sudo usermod -aG docker vagrant`. This will add vagrant to docker group, verify that as well & log out & login back.

Comment: hihi I did this sudo usermod -aG docker oracle. Apologies its not vagrant. 

then exit exit. service docker restart still didnt work.

Comment: After restart, do another `exit` & retry after starting a SSH session again.

Comment: Did that didnt work as well. From what i understand the jenkins users resides in docker container itself right? So I cant do a sudo usermod -aG docker oracle.

Comment: Problem here is your user is not able to run docker commands and your user is not `jenkins`. So fix permissions of your user to run docker commands first.

Comment: Hi hi I did fix oracle to be able to run docker commands. I can run docker commands login as oracle.

Comment: [oracle@OL74-ClientImage ~]$ grep /etc/group -e "docker"
docker:x:982:oracle

Answer (score 1):

Check below settings,

1. The user with which you are running docker run command might not be able to connect with docker, so in that case you need to do

   `usermod -aG docker <username>`

After this, logout from current session, and login again.

2. Check your docker service

   `systemctl status docker.service`

If not running,
systemctl start docker.service

Comment: Hi tried this but it didnt work. TO be clear I did install jenkins and I did a docker pull od jenkins image. So how do i add jenkins user?

Comment: Once your user is able to connect with docker you just need to run  "docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkinsci/blueocean" and access jenkins with http://<server-ip>:8080